# Simpler modulus operation by splitting number

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Someone just shared some code with me that attempts to calculate modulus of big numbers in a more simple way, but I don't quite understand how it works.

If you want to know $a$ modulus $b$, where $a$ is some big number, you can split a into digits: $a = a_1 a_2...a_n$ (so to be clear, this is not multiplication, it means 123 = 1 and 2 and 3). Then, you can (seemingly arbitrarily) pick groups of digits to calculate it modulus $b$. For every group, you prepend the outcome to the next group: $a_1a_2a_3 \mod b = x$, then $xa_4a_5 \mod b = y$, then $ya_6...a_n \mod b = z$ where z = a mod b. Here is an example:

```
77766655544 mod 98
> 7776665 mod 98 = 71
> 715544 mod 98 = 46 = 77766655544 mod 98
```

How does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple result derived from [basic properties of modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Properties). First, you can split the number:
$$77766655544 \bmod 98 = (77766650000 \bmod 98)+(5544 \bmod 98)$$
Now, based on the fact that
$$7776665 \bmod 98 = 71 \\
\implies 7776665 \equiv 71 \pmod{98}
$$
you can derive (by multiplying by $10000$)
$$ \implies 77766650000 \equiv 710000 \pmod{98}$$
and replace in the original equation
$$ (77766650000 \bmod 98)+(5544 \bmod 98) \\
= (710000 \bmod 98)+(5544 \bmod 98) \\
= 715544 \bmod 98
$$
In essence, these properties allow one to process huge numbers with large counts of digits by iteratively processing smaller "chunks" of it.